# flutter: how to register an object to provider with name and get by name

Tags: flutter, provider

I want to use Provider as dependency injection tool. However, I want to inject two values with the same type `Map<String, String>`, such as

```
Provider.value(objectA);
Provider.value(objectB)
```

where both `objectA` and `objectB` are `Map<String, String>`.

How can I give names to each of them and then use the name to retrieve different values?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create two different classes and put your maps inside them as members:

```
class ClassA with ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<String, String> myMap = {};
  ClassA({this.myMap});
}
class ClassB with ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<String, String> myMap = {};
  ClassB({this.myMap});
}
```

And then you can create, consume and lookup the different providers:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ClassA()),
```

```
Consumer<ClassB>(builder: (context, myClassB, child) {return ...;})
```

```
context.read<ClassA>()...
```